# Как запретить нажатие клавиши Enter для кнопки?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

У меня есть некий *"Кликер Монет"*. Но если нажать один раз на кнопку, то в будущем можно будет просто зажать клавишу *Enter* и счётчик монет будет разрываться от кликов. А таким образом можно будет без труда набрать много монет, что мне не нужно. Как это предотвратить?

Comment: Вам нужно запретить полностью эту кнопку или сделать так, чтобы она срабатывала в опр. интервал времени?

Comment: Мне нужно полностью запретить нажатие клавиши Enter. В крайнем случае поставить интервал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените кнопку на `div` (например). Визуально этот див может выглядеть как кнопка, но нажать Enter на нём будет нельзя.

UPD

```
var buttonEL = document.querySelector('div');
buttonEL.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Клик, но не нажатие');
});
```

Comment: Можно написать if (event.keyCode == 13) return

Comment: @vaytonqueen добавил пример кода. Но обратите внимание, что кликать можно программно. Опытные пользователи могут легко написать бота, хотя скорее всего просто поменяют количество монет через консоль.

Comment: А если, например, сразу кол-во монет отправлять в БД?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко а пробел тоже можно нажимать. И хоткей, если он есть.

Comment: @Егор Банин, так он хотел только enter запретить)

Comment: @vaytonqueen зависит от задачи. Во некоторых играх на это забивают (пользователь сам лишает себя удовольствия от игры, если хакает приложение), в некоторых вводят проверки. Пользователь и в базу может послать миллион.

Comment: Спасибо! А не могли бы Вы ответить мне ещё на один вопрос? Как отображать, скажем, счётчик монет в РЕАЛЬНОМ времени? Мой счётчик обновляется только при нажатии на кнопку. А если у меня будет возможность в игре купить авто-ферму монет, скажем, по 1 монете в 3 секунды? Счётчик и в этом случае должен обновляться, даже без клика на кнопку (обработка и прибавление монет к счётчику происходит в функции, которая вызывается при помощи onclick)

Comment: @vaytonqueen напишите функцию автофермы (setInterval). Когда у пользователя она куплена, запускайте её -- монеты побежали.

Comment: Так проблема в том, что отображаться всё это будет только после нажатия на кнопку. Пусть их хоть миллион набежит, отобразятся только после клика на кнопкую

Comment: @vaytonqueen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LwVxJy